# How to check last modified date of a file in AIX using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, date, aix

I want to check last modified date of a file in AIX using bash script.

I ve tried,

```
date -r file.txt "+%m-%d-%Y"
stat -c %y file.txt
```

but not working in AIX.

Comment: `not working` - what do you mean by that? Do you get any errors? Messages? The output is invalid? In wrong format?

Comment: "date: Not a recognized flag: r"  this is what im getting.

Comment: What happens on `stat -c %y file.txt`?

Comment: stat is not an available command in AIX

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find an appropriately specific utility, you can always fall back on perl:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'printf "%s\n", strftime("%c", localtime((stat(shift @ARGV))[8]))' filename
```

or more legibly:

```
perl -e '
    use POSIX qw(strftime);
    my $filename  = shift @ARGV;
    my @filedata  = stat $filename;
    my $mtime     = $filedata[8];
    my @timedata  = localtime $mtime;
    my $timestamp = strftime "%c", @timedata;
    print "$timestamp\n";
' filename
```

Choose a strftime format to your liking. If you just need the epoch time, print `$mtime`.

Comment: Heh. `+1` for adding the legible version ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
istat file
Inode 263 on device 10/8        File
Protection: rw-r--r--
Owner: 0(root)          Group: 0(system)
Link count:   1         Length 14682 bytes

Last updated:   Tue Sep 15 10:50:15 PDT 2018
Last modified:  Tue Sep 15 10:50:15 PDT 2018
Last accessed:  Tue Nov  3 12:01:12 PST 2018
```

In case you haven't figured it out yet:

```
date -d "$( istat file | awk '/modified/{gsub( /^[^:]+: +/,"",$0); print}' )"   "+%m-%d-%Y"
```

P.S.: `"+%m-%d-%Y"` is a silly date format, because it doesn't sort naturally.  `"+%Y-%m-%d"` would make far more sense.

Comment: I just want to store date of modification of a file in a variable(just date in ddmmyyy format).

Comment: I hope `awk` and `date` on AIX behave the same as mine ;) @Rajs